# how to find out missing numbers in sql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sorting

In my case There are port in between two ranges which start from  7001 to 7050. If somebody has taken 40 of the port numbers so how i can find out the available  port number in between these ranges of number.

**For example** 
A person take 7003 and 7012 port number so how i can figure out that 7004 to 7011 are available for me

help me out please

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `status` column that can take 0 when the port is free, and 1 when it is occupied.

```
ALTER TABLE your_port_table ADD `status` INT DEFAULT 0;
```

So you can easily just run the query below to get a free port with the smallest port number:

```
SELECT port_number
FROM your_port_table
WHERE `status`=0
ORDER BY port_number DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new column in table like port_status
After that When user take port, then you update value 1 in port_status column.

Then you fetch record like

```
Select * from table_name where port_status=0
```

Then you will all port that is not taken by user

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure with the answer but you may check this query

```
select min_a - 1 + level
 from ( select min(a) min_a
             , max(a) max_a
          from test1
      )
connect by level <= max_a - min_a + 1
minus
 select a
 from test1
```

Result will be:

```
MIN_A-1+LEVEL
-------------
     7003
     7007
     7008
     7009
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of nested subquery you can use it as a reference

```
SELECT your-cloumn
FROM ports
WHERE EXISTS 
  (
   SELECT *
   FROM ports
   WHERE your-column BETWEEN your-column AND your-column
  )
```